# Date pipe can be use in component class of angular 10

Tags: angular

```
import { Constants } from './../util/constants';
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';

@Pipe({
  name: 'dateFormat'
})
export class DateFormatPipe extends DatePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    return super.transform(value, Constants.DATE_FMT);
  }
}
```

Above is my datepipe class..am using in angular html code to convert date ..Is is same can be re-use /inject in my component class ?

Please let me know..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to provide it in the module, or if you need only in one specific component you can provide it in the component.

```
@NgModule({....
providers: [ 
    DateFormatPipe,
] 
})
export class AppCommonModule { }
```

or

```
@Component({
   ...
   providers: [DateFormatPipe]
}) 
export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit { ..
```

then you inject it in your component and use it like this

```
constructor(private dateformat: DateFormatPipe) { 
    let formattedDate = dateformat.transform(new Date());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

when you create a PIPE class you can use it anywhere in your application if you inject it in the app.module.

You can directly use it in any HTML template provided that it is already provided in that module.

there are two types of pipe: Pure and Impure - based on angular change detection

for more details you can check out this link:

https://indepth.dev/posts/1061/the-essential-difference-between-pure-and-impure-pipes-in-angular-and-why-that-matters

Comment: Yes ..I have shared module..injected in that...isnit possible to use that pipe dateFormat in service/component.ts file?

Comment: Yes, you can it is similar to the services. You can inject it similarly and use the transform method. you can use this link - https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/using-angular-pipes-in-components-or-services/#:~:text=We%20usually%20use%20Angular%20Pipes,an%20angular%20component%20or%20service.